# WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup

Tags: websphere

I am doing dynamic clustering the cluster member did not start and the following error occured 
WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:490)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:539)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:523)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:310)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:223)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:686)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:380)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:151)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:867)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:166)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1277)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1694)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:371)
        at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.(EJSServerORBImpl.java:102)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:55)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:482)
        ... 34 more

Comment: If you add in some English to go with this wall of errors, you'll have a better chance at getting this question answered. See [these question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I had the same error, this answer was the first on my google seatch! Cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually means that the bootstrap port (default 2809 for single server, or 9809/9810 for ND) is in use by another process.