# Websphere Application Server is not starting in Eclipse Mars

Tags: websphere, eclipse-mars

I have just Installed the WebSphere Application Server, The status on localHost shows its started but when I try to start it from Eclipse I am getting following :

```
[00000000 WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:520)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:298)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:666)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:330)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:108)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:866)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:604)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:151)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1231)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1681)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:364)
    at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:420)
    ... 29 more
```

What may be the reason behind this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044623/wsvr0009e-error-occurred-during-startup)

Comment: You said it's already started, but you're trying to start it again?

Comment: I am getting that error message on eclipse when trying to start the server but in the localhost the status of the server can be seen as started.

Comment: You can't start it in Eclipse if it's already started outside Eclipse. That error likely just means that it's already started.